# Dash escaping hyphen?

Tags: osx, escape-characters, dash

I am using Homebrews dash package on MacOS to print a text.

```
echo "Hello World  - Test"
```

But I am receiving

```
Hello World  \- Test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually the escaping is also happening in strings in general, I guess:

    echo "Page 1" | grep "^Page [0-9]" 

is not working either

Comment: Cannot reproduce on dash 0.5.9.1 on Linux (just a data point)

Comment: i don't know what the Dash package is, but if I type echo "Hello World - Test" i get just that:  Hello World - Test

Comment: On macOS 12.5, with Homebrew 3.5.8 and Dash 0.5.11.5, the hyphen is correctly printed.